# How to scrape all the home page text content of a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining

So I am new to webscraping, I want to scrape all the text content of only the home page.

this is my code, but it now working correctly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


website_url = "http://www.traiteurcheminfaisant.com/"
ra = requests.get(website_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ra.text, "html.parser")

full_text = soup.find_all()

print(full_text)
```

When I print "full_text" it give me a lot of html content but not all, when I  `ctrl + f " traiteurcheminfaisant@hotmail.com"` the email adress that is on the home page (footer) 
is not found on full_text.

Thanks you for helping!

Comment: If you print(ra.text) or (soup.text), you'll get the complete html including the email address. I'm not sure why BS4 is not returning the email address but I'm guessing it has something to do with how the BS4 find_function works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick glance at the website that you're attempting to scrape from makes me suspect that not all content is loaded when sending a simple get request via the requests module. In other words, it seems likely that some components on the site, such as the footer you mentioned, are being loaded asynchronously with Javascript.

If that is the case, you'll probably want to use some sort of automation tool to navigate to the page, wait for it to load and then parse the fully loaded source code. For this, the most common tool would be Selenium. It can be a bit tricky to set up the first time since you'll also need to install a separate webdriver for whatever browser you'd like to use. That said, the last time I set this up it was pretty easy. Here's a rough example of what this might look like for you (once you've got Selenium properly set up):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/your/path/to/geckodriver')
driver.get('http://www.traiteurcheminfaisant.com')
time.sleep(2)

source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

full_text = soup.find_all()

print(full_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used BeatifulSoup before, but try using urlopen instead. This will store the webpage as a string, which you can use to find the email.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

try:
    response = urlopen("http://www.traiteurcheminfaisant.com")
    html = response.read().decode(encoding = "UTF8", errors='ignore')
    print(html.find("traiteurcheminfaisant@hotmail.com"))
except:
    print("Cannot open webpage")
```